# Xamarin.iOS - How to implement a simple grid with images

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I need to implement a `UIViewController`, with a grid inside that has dynamic columns and dynamic rows. I was editing [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_collection_views/) sample, but it is a circle with images.

I assume that I have to edit the following file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using CoreAnimation;
using UIKit;

namespace SimpleCollectionView
{
public class CircleLayout : UICollectionViewLayout
{
    const float ItemSize = 70.0f;
    int cellCount = 20;
    float radius;
    CGPoint center;

    static NSString myDecorationViewId = new NSString ("MyDecorationView");

    public CircleLayout ()
    {
        RegisterClassForDecorationView (typeof(MyDecorationView), myDecorationViewId);
    }

    public override void PrepareLayout ()
    {
        base.PrepareLayout ();

        CGSize size = CollectionView.Frame.Size;
        cellCount = (int)CollectionView.NumberOfItemsInSection (0);
        center = new CGPoint (size.Width / 2.0f, size.Height / 2.0f);
        radius = (float)Math.Min (size.Width, size.Height) / 2.5f;
    }

    public override CGSize CollectionViewContentSize {
        get {
            return CollectionView.Frame.Size;
        }
    }

    public override bool ShouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange (CGRect newBounds)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes LayoutAttributesForItem (NSIndexPath path)
    {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes.CreateForCell (path);
        attributes.Size = new CGSize (ItemSize, ItemSize);
        attributes.Center = new CGPoint (center.X + radius * (float)Math.Cos (2 * path.Row * Math.PI / cellCount),
                                        center.Y + radius * (float)Math.Sin (2 * path.Row * Math.PI / cellCount));
        return attributes;
    }

    public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[] LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect (CGRect rect)
    {
        var attributes = new UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes [cellCount + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < cellCount; i++) {
            NSIndexPath indexPath = NSIndexPath.FromItemSection (i, 0);
            attributes [i] = LayoutAttributesForItem (indexPath);
        }

        var decorationAttribs = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes.CreateForDecorationView (myDecorationViewId, NSIndexPath.FromItemSection (0, 0));
        decorationAttribs.Size = CollectionView.Frame.Size;
        decorationAttribs.Center = CollectionView.Center;
        decorationAttribs.ZIndex = -1;
        attributes [cellCount] = decorationAttribs;

        return attributes;
    }

}

public class MyDecorationView : UICollectionReusableView
{
    [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
    public MyDecorationView (CGRect frame) : base (frame)
    {
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    }
}
}
```

However, I really don't know what I have to modify to get a simple image grid with rows and columns.

I didn't find any real examples for this, so maybe someone can help me find a useful example.

Comment: Isn't the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` what you're looking for? https://developer.xamarin.com/Guides/ios/User_Interface/Introduction_to_Collection_Views/#Flow_Layout